# How to overlay text on to an awesomewm widget?

Tags: awesome-wm

Over the years I've used conky for most of this stuff, and I currently have a conky-only bottom bar for this purpose. I'm trying to rewrite parts/all of it in awesomewm, but I'm hung up on one thing.

With conky it's trivial to overlay text on something else (normally a graph), just by getting a new line and doing a voffset.

awesomewm, obviously, has a different paradigm. Is there any core (v4) way to achieve the same effect of text overlaying a graph/progressbar? So for example a graph of CPU activity with an overlay showing cpu_p or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's trivial an Awesome 4.0+ too, you need to use a `wibox.layout.stack` to place a `wibox.widget.textbox` on top of the `wibox.widget.graph`. See the first example in the progressbar documentation:

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/widgets/wibox.widget.progressbar.html

Comment: That's... way easier than I thought it would be. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to post your result in https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1395 once you are done!

Comment: the link is changed, try this https://elv13.github.io/widgets/wibox.widget.progressbar.html